# Mozilla FB Container not auto enabled

Tags: facebook, firefox, firefox-addon

I installed the [Mozilla Facebook Container](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/facebook-container/) Add-on and as per the instructions:

> Installing this extension deletes your Facebook cookies and logs you
>   out of Facebook. The next time you navigate to Facebook it will load
>   in a new blue colored browser tab (the “Container”).

This, however, did not work for me. 
[image: FB Tab]

I have the Add-on installed:
[image]

Is there a step that I need to take that is not documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and support at containers@mozilla.com told me that if I have "never remember history" checked in my privacy preferences, Facebook Container will not work.

I went to Preferences > Privacy & Security > History and changed it to "remember history," and now the Facebook Container works. (Unfortunately, I guess you can't have both?)

Answer (score 1):

The notes from the extension pages report the following:

> NOTE: If you are a Multi-Account Containers user who has already
>   assigned Facebook to a Container, **this extension will not work**. In an
>   effort to preserve your existing Container set up and logins, this
>   add-on will not include the additional protection to keep other sites
>   out of your Facebook Container. If you would like this additional
>   protection, first unassign facebook.com in the Multi-Account Container
>   extension, and then install this extension.

It also suggests where to file issues if something goes wrong: that might be a better place to get some help.

> Report Issues If you come across any issues with this extension,
>   please let us know by filing an issue here or by emailing
>   containers@mozilla.com. Thank you!